# Solution of a trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

> $$\sin^2 (x) \cos (x) = \sin(x)\cos^2 (x)$$

Solution:

$$\begin{align*}
&\sin^2(x)\cos(x)=\sin(x)\cos^2(x)\iff\\
&\sin(x)\cos(x)=\cos^2(x)\iff\\
&\sin(x)\cos(x)-\cos^2(x)=0\iff\\
&\cos(x)\big(\sin(x)-\cos(x)\big)=0\\
&\cos(x)=0\lor\cos(x)=\sin(x)\iff\\
&x=\frac{\pi}2+2k\pi\quad (k\in\Bbb Z)\lor x=\frac{\pi}4+k\pi\quad (k\in\Bbb Z)
\end{align*}$$

This solution has one or more mistakes; could someone help me find them?

Comment: In your first step you divided by $\sin x$; this is not valid if $\sin x=0$, and in fact the angles $x$ such that $\sin x=0$ are all solutions. Rewrite the equation as $$\sin x\cos x(\sin x-\cos x)=0$$ and solve $\sin x=0$, $\cos x=0$, and $\sin x=\cos x$. The last occurs when $\tan x=\ldots\;$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Could you please convert your comment into an answer so this question can be removed from the "Unanswered" queue?